# SQL Server Log Shipping and creating a user on secondary server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, log-shipping

We have server `A` that is our production server, we are using SQL Server log shipping to ship transaction logs from server `A` to `B`.

I understand that server `B` is then in a warm-standby read-only state.

My question is, how can we add a windows domain account to have read-only access to that database on server `B` but not have access to the database on server `A`.

When I try to create a user and assign read-only access to server `B`, I cant of course be because server `B` is in standbay mode. How can I get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a restore of the log shipping secondary with the standby option and make the secondary readable. One caveat though is that you can't restore any further logs until you revert to your standby file.

Comment: Can you explain, im not sure I understand. Thanks

Comment: Okay. On your log shipping secondary, you can do "restore secondary_database with standby = 'path_to_standby_file'". To put the database back into a state where you can restore log files, it looks like you just restore a log file. Check the section on standby here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178615

Answer (score 0):

If server A and server B are replicate with log shipping, the db should be the same, what is the reason behind if read only user account cannot access server A ?

BTW , if you really need this feature, you should use SQL replication instead of log shipping, since SQL replication on server B is online, u can add extra users to the DB